# python import not working eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I just started to learn python and I am not able to import any other module in eclipse.
I have created 1 file called

```
module.py
```

that holds this

```
def test():
    print("this is a test")
```

but when i tried to import it in another file in eclipse  (test.py) it does not recognize it

```
import module
```

i am getting the following error

```
Unresolved import: module
Unused import: module
――――――――――――――――――――
module Found at: myPckg.test

import module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem
i needed to add

```
import myPckg.module
```

like i wrote "I just started to learn.." :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try rename module.py to something my_module.py

Else you could try: from my_module import test

module.py

```
def test():
    print("test")
```

main.py

```
from module import test
if __name__ == '__main__':

    test()
```

Comment: Create new PyDev project add main.py and module.py to it. Press Run. Or simply rename test.py